# Dynamic default parameters in python

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments, keyword

I am making a function for buttons, it accepts a keyword (or default, idk what the term is) argument for mouse position, is there a way i can set the default value to be whatever a variable is.

```
mousepos = (0, 0) #initialise mouse variable
def mousecheck(mouse=mousepos):
    return hitbox.collisioncheck(mouse)

while True:
    mousepos = get_mouse_pos()
    mousecheck()
```

What happens is that when the function is defined, it sets the default value of mouse to mousepos, which is (0, 0). What i want is for the default value to be whatever mousepos is at the time of the call.

Comment: Is there a reason you dont want to pass `mousepos` into `mousecheck`? Eg `mousecheck(mousepos)`? Or call `get_mouse_pos` inside `mousecheck`?

Comment: i'm just trying to make very generalised code, so that myself and others can use, mousePos seemed like a very normal name for a mouse position so i wanted it to try to default to mousepos if left blank

Answer (score 0):

By default set your mousepos to None, and then inside the function check if it is None or already a value is passed.
If it is none, assign the global value to it.

```
mousepos = (0, 0) #initialise mouse variable
def mousecheck(mouse=None):
    global mousepos
    if(mouse is None):
        mouse=mousepos
    return hitbox.collisioncheck(mouse)

while True:
    mousepos = get_mouse_pos()
    mousecheck()
```

Comment: global variables can make code harder to maintain and test since the function depends on a variable outside of its scope.  Can lead to bugs and unintended behavior if the mousepos variable is modified accidentally elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @yashaswikakumanu understandable. but the requirement was to read the value of the global variable at the time of the function call